# Oracle: Analytical functions Sub totals after each change in value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, gaps-and-islands, subtotal

I have the following data (order of records as in the example):

```
A   B
1   10
1   20
1   30
1   40
2   50
2   65
2   75
1   89
1   100
```

from SQL:

```
with x as (
  select A, B
  from (
    select 1 as A, 10 as B from dual
    union all
    select 1 as A, 20 as B from dual
    union all
    select 1 as A, 30 as B from dual
    union all
    select 1 as A, 40 as B from dual
    union all
    select 2 as A, 50 as B from dual
    union all
    select 2 as A, 65 as B from dual
    union all
    select 2 as A, 75 as B from dual
    union all
    select 1 as A, 89 as B from dual
    union all
    select 1 as A, 100 as B from dual
  ) 
)
select A, B
from X
```

I want to group the data for each change of value in column A,
I want to get the following result:

```
A   MIN(B)  MAX(B) 
1   10      40
2   50      75
1   89      100
```

How to get such a result in the ORACLE 11. I would expect a simple implementation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem, solved using `row_number` analytic function

```
SELECT a,
       MIN(b),
       MAX(b)
FROM (
     SELECT x.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 ORDER BY b
            ) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY a
                 ORDER BY b
            ) AS seq
     FROM x
)
GROUP BY a,
         seq;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d60dbda4f11041cbf16f4ea554c1c29a)

Comment: it does not work: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b586f8685a43c301b54aa3ebfbf96bf)

Comment: @TomaszTomzik : It works, just add `order by min(b)` See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce14558640b26a88814037304ac8a5c3)

Comment: @TomaszTomzik, RDBMS does not and can not guarantee the order of the records returned from a query without an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: .... but, it only works if column b is unique... [LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5344070acdad324a97c35e07fad1451e)

Comment: @TomaszTomzik : Yes, that's true. So, it's important to have a Unique key / Primary which increments and indicates a proper sequence, other than A and B. Or else the database has no idea what order you desire.

Comment: but this is no longer a big problem, I can group data ;)

Comment: @TomaszTomzik kindly you can try to accept the answer (*seems it helped*).

Comment: I know, this field is a date that could have been repeated but it's not a problem anymore;)